# Counting items in multiple tests in exam latex

Tags: exam

I need to put more than one test in a booklet, and each test is followed by a short statistics (counting questions and total points). However, Tex tends to count the total number of questions and points in the whole booklet. How to have a separate stat for each test?

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,final,leqno]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, latexsym, amscd, amsthm}
 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\section{Test A  }
\begin{questions}
    \addpoints 
 
    \question[3] Amanda wrote down four numbers.
    The mean of these numbers is 15, the median is  
 
    \question[3] The surface area of a sphere is directly proportional to the square of its  
    
    \question[4] Find all the pairs $(x,y)$ of real numbers such that 
    
    \[ 
    \begin{cases}
    x+y+\frac xy=13,\\
    \frac{x(x+y)}y=36.
    \end{cases}
    \]
     

        \rule{5cm}{.7pt}
    
    \numquestions{} questions, \numpages{} pages (including the cover) for the total of \numpoints{}  marks.
    
\end{questions}
 
%   \combinedgradetable[v][questions]
 

\pagebreak
\section{Test B  }

 
\begin{questions}
    \addpoints
    \question[2] The average age of 33 fifth$-$graders is 11. The average age of  55 of  

    \question[3]   Ming and Catherine walked to the store together to buy some pencils. Ming bought  

    \question[3] The lengths of the sides of a triangle in inches are three consecutive  
    
    
\question[3] If $x+y-2z=13$, $x+y+4z=10$, and $x-y+z=14$, find $x-y$. 


    \rule{5cm}{.7pt}

\numquestions{} questions, \numpages{} pages (including the cover) for the total of \numpoints{}  marks.
 

\end{questions}

\newpage 
 
\section{Test C  }
\begin{questions}
    \addpoints
    \question[3] 
    On a map, a straight road measuring 600 m is represented by a line segment of length 7.5 cm.
    
  
    \question[4] If $x,y$ are integers such that $-8\leq x\leq 7$ and $-1\leq y\leq 6$, find 
  
\question[4] This question has two parts. 
  
    \rule{5cm}{.7pt}

\numquestions{} questions, \numpages{} pages (including the cover) for the total of \numpoints{}  marks.

\end{questions} 
    \end{document}
```

Comment: `latexsym` is an old package: `amssymb` have more symbols instead of `latexsym`.